# Why is Spring Security forbidding a specific resource regardless of role?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am developing a web application using Spring MVC architecture and securing it with Spring security. I'm using JPA repositories for my persistence layer. The issue I'm having is that when I attempt to send a POST request from a specific page in the application ("Add implementation" page), I get an error page with this message:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Forbidden
```

This happens regardless of which role my user has (there are two roles: `admin` and `vendor`). In addition, this even happens when I explicitly permit the Url in question in my `configure(HttpSecurity http)` function using `antMatchers` and `permitAll()`. So the question is, why is my POST request not being authorized?

I'm pretty new to Spring Security and may have made a critical error in any of the configurations therein. I'll attach all code related to Spring security, as well as the controller in question.

Below is my configure function: The url `/vendor/{id:[0-9]+}/addimpl` is the one giving me trouble. I have explicitly permitted it here just to see what would happen, but I'm still getting a `403` error when posting to it (but the GET request works fine).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AcvpUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/webjars/**", "/css/**",
                    "/images/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vendor/{id:[0-9]+}/addimpl").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}
```

Here is my `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AcvpUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AcvpUserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        AcvpUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new AcvpUserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

And the UserDetails class...

```
@Transactional
public class AcvpUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

/**
 * this is necessary for posterity to know whether they can serialize this
 * class safely
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3771770649711489402L;
private AcvpUser user;

public AcvpUserPrincipal(AcvpUser user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {   
    return Collections.singletonList(new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword(); // this is now the encrypted password
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {    
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

And here is my `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` class. An instance of this is returned from `myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()` in the configure function.

```
public class AcvpAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Autowired
private AcvpUserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
  throws IOException {

    handle(request, response, authentication);
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}

protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
  throws IOException {

    String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        logger.debug(
          "Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to "
          + targetUrl);
        return;
    }

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}

protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
    boolean isUser = false;
    boolean isAdmin = false;
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
     = authentication.getAuthorities();
    for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
        if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(AcvpRoles.VENDOR_ROLE)) {
            isUser = true;
            break;
        } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(AcvpRoles.ADMIN_ROLE)) {
            isAdmin = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isUser) {        
        String username = authentication.getName();
        AcvpUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);     
        return "/vendor/" + user.getVendor().getId();
    } else if (isAdmin) {
        return "/";
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        return;
    }
    session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
}

public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
    this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
}
protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
    return redirectStrategy;
}
}
```

Here are the Spring Security dependencies from my pom file:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the controller function. I'm including both the GET and the POST but note that the GET works fine, while the POST gives the error. I'll point out though that the program DOES NOT enter the POST function. I set a breakpoint and attempted to debug, but it crashed before entering this function.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vendor/{id:[0-9]+}/addimpl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddImplementation(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id)
        throws VendorNotFoundException {
    Vendor vendor = vendorRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(VendorNotFoundException::new);
    model.addAttribute("vendor", vendor);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("moduleTypes", ModuleType.values());
    ImplementationAddForm backingObject = new ImplementationAddForm();
    model.addAttribute("form", backingObject);
    return "implementation-add-edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/vendor/{id:[0-9]+}/addimpl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveImplementation(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @ModelAttribute("implementation") @Valid ImplementationAddForm form,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes ra)
        throws VendorNotFoundException {
    Vendor vendor = vendorRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(VendorNotFoundException::new);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("vendor", vendor);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("moduleTypes", ModuleType.values());
        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        return "implementation-add-edit";
    } else {
        Implementation i = form.buildEntity();
        i.setVendor(vendor);
        implementationRepository.save(i);
        return "redirect:/vendor/" + id;
    }

}
```

Finally, I'm including the output from setting "debug" on the SecurityConfiguration class. This might help, but I wasn't able to get anything from it.

```
Request received for POST '/vendor/33/addimpl':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3b981cfd

servletPath:/vendor/33/addimpl
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 402
cache-control: max-age=0
origin: http://localhost:8080
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
referer: http://localhost:8080/vendor/33/addimpl
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=1121ADD15A2E23786464649647B62356


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


 ************************************************************


2018-12-21 09:49:32.570  INFO 4392 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] Spring Security 
Debugger                 : 

 ************************************************************

Request received for POST '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@73210c23

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 402
cache-control: max-age=0
origin: http://localhost:8080
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
referer: http://localhost:8080/vendor/33/addimpl
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=1121ADD15A2E23786464649647B62356


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

After sending the POST request to `/vendor/33/addimpl`, I expect to be redirected back to the Vendor page, or to the "add implementation" page again (the very page I posted from), in the event of a validation error. But none of these are occurring. I am instead sent to a default error page.

Comment: I don't see the CSRF token in the POST request. By default Spring Security has it enabled. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the issue was that CSRF was enabled and the CSRF token was not being sent with the POST request. I did not, however, wish to disable CSRF entirely, as I wanted the app secure from CSRF attacks. It turns out that adding the CSRF token in this application is very easy. I am using thymeleaf as my templating tool, and this simple solution is not found in any of the links already posted, but it is found here: https://www.baeldung.com/csrf-thymeleaf-with-spring-security

I included this code in my login form:

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

According to the above link, this is all that is necessary but for me it didn't work until I added thymeleaf `th:` notation to all my form actions. So instead of doing `<form action="<url>"` I had to do `<form th:action="@{<url>}"`.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery) is enabled by default.

You may want to turn it off in your AcvpUserDetailsService  class

Add:

```
 http.csrf().disable();
```

Read more about CSRF here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But is it a good idea to just disable csrf? Why isn't my application providing a csrf token with the request?

Comment: Looks like I can find the answers in the links you and Angelo Immediata referred me to. Thanks.